# Deserialize XML Element with only one attribute and no value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

My XML has elements with only one attribute and no value. In my example the element "validity".

Snippet of my XML:

```
<master V="01101">
    <last_changed>2013-01-01</last_changed>
    <validity V="1994-01-01.."/>
</master>
```

XML classes as I would do it:

```
[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Master
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string V { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string last_changed { get; set; }
    public Validity validity { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Validity
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string V { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way that I do not need the additional class for the only one attribute of "validity"?

Comment: If you want using attributes for serialization then you need own class for `validity` element which will contains `V` property marked as attribute. What is wrong with using a class for that?

Comment: Simplicity. For an element with only a value I need a property in class Master. For an element with only one attribute I need an extra class.

Comment: It is not simplicity. If you will have possibility to not create a class for element with one attribute, how you will define than element which have two attributes.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. For example, use a custom `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`. Or implement an `IXmlSerializable` interface. Thus, it is possible to get rid of extra class, but the overall amount of code will probably increase.